# How do I enable mouse only for a particular split screen in VIM?

Tags: windows, vim, nerdtree

I'm using NERDTree with mintty and cygwin on Windows.
Is there a way to enable mouse only for the NERDTree split screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The `mouse` option is enabled/disabled globally.

Comment: Maybe somehow to enable it only when the focus is on the split screan and disable it on focus lost?

Comment: I don't use NERDTree so I can't test it but you should be able to write an `autocmd` that checks for the window name and enables/disables `mouse`. But, if you don't use your mouse, the `mouse` option doesn't do anything good or bad so… you could just set it globally and forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is!  I had the same question, since while setting mouse=a works to enable NERDTree mouse navigation, I didn't want to lose the easy "mouse-selected-text-is-automatically-copied" functionality I'm addicted to.

Building on @romainl's idea, here is a vimscript snippet that works when vim is opened with a file, as well as when you switch in and out of NERDTree windows:

```
function NERDTreeMouse()
    if (&ft ==? "nerdtree")
        set mouse=a
    else
        set mouse=
    endif
endfunction

au FileType * :call NERDTreeMouse()
au WinEnter * :call NERDTreeMouse()
au WinLeave * :call NERDTreeMouse()
```

Of course, don't forget to enable `NERDTreeMouseMode` with your preferred setting.  Setting it to 2 will open directory nodes on a single click, file nodes with a double click. `:help NERDTreeMouseMode` for more.

```
let g:NERDTreeMouseMode=2
```

Tested on CentOS Linux 7.6.1810 with

- `vim` 7.4
- NERDTree 5.0.0

... but I expect it will work on cygwin.  If it doesn't please comment.